# MySQL duplicate key error

Tags: mysql

If I run this code all work well, but  if uncomment last constraint, I got the following error:

> Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'transfer'

but there no another key 'fk_component_id', what wrong with this code?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pcdb`.`transfer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pcdb`.`transfer` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `component_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NULL,
  `parent_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `source_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `contractor_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `src_department_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `dest_department_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `session_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `count` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT(65535) NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_src_department_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`src_department_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`department` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_income_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`transfer` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contractor_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contractor_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`contractor` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_session_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`session_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`session` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dest_department_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dest_department_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`department` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`transfer` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION/*, 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_component_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`)
    REFERENCES `pcdb`.`component` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION*/);
```

Comment: Is there a key in component_id?

Comment: -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pcdb`.`component`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pcdb`.`component` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may already have a constraint with that name on a different table in the database. Try changing the name of that constraint to something like "fk_transfer_component_id" and see if you still get the error.

Comment: yes, it helps, I just think foreign key should be unique per table, but it seems that it should be unique in the entire scheme